# Question concerning the linear independence of $\{1,x,....x^m\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

In “Linear Algebra Done Right” by Axler, to prove that the set $S=\{1, x, …x^m\}$ is linearly independent in $P(F)$, where $P(F)$ denotes the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $F$ and $m$ is a nonnegative integer, the following argument is used:  Suppose that $a_0, a_1,…a_m \in F$ such that $a_0+a_1 x+….a_m x^m = 0$. If at least one of the $a_i$ were non-zero, then the above equation could be satisfied by at most $m$ distinct values of $x$. This contradiction shows that all $a_i=0$. Hence, S is linearly independent.

Could anyone tell where the contradiction is in the above reasoning? Why can’t $x$ take at most $m$ distinct values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a linear relation
$$
f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_mx^m = 0
$$
then you are saying that this polynomial is *identically* zero; that is, it is zero for *every possibly input $x$*. However, if one of the $a_i$ is non-zero, then it is a well-known fact that a polynomial of degree $m$ has at most $m$ roots; that is, there are at most $m$ possible values $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ such that $f(x_i) = 0$. Assuming $F$ is a field with more than $m$ elements, this is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I understand now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Polynomials are the vectors. When one writes an equality such as

$$a_0+a_1x + a_2x^2=0$$

Then it means the equality is satisfied **for all** x. It might help to not think of the right-hand side as 0, as in the scalar. Rather it is the zero vector which you can think of as the polynomial $\textbf{0}(x)$

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now. :)